# How do i make auto shipping programatically in magento?

Tags: php, magento

I tried with following observer code.

```
...
    public function automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder($observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->getCollection()
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('order_id', array('eq'=>$order->getId()));
        $orders->getSelect()->limit(1);
        if ((int)$orders->count() !== 0) {
            return $this;
        }
        try {
               if($order->canShip())
                {
                $itemQty =  $order->getItemsCollection()->count();
                $items[] = $itemQty;
                // This first definition and 2nd look overlapping, our one is obsolete?
                $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($itemQty);
                $ship = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
                $shipmentId = $ship->create($order->getId(), $items, 'Shipment created through ShipMailInvoice', true, true); 
//getting Error here

                }
              }
} catch (Exception $e) {
                $order->addStatusHistoryComment(' Exception occurred during automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder action. Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
                $order->save();
            }
return $this;
    }
.....
```

When i place the order, i can capture the order success event using observer. Finally getting "`Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!`" in ajax call itself.

I could not found the solution. Kindly give some advice on this

Comment: What event exactly is being captured?

Comment: @OlegIshenko i use sales_order_save_after event

Comment: there you have it, as Kalpesh Mehta said, it is an infinite chain of events, which Magento breaks after 100 iterations

Answer (score 2):

Each time your order is saved, this observer method is called, which again saves your order due to some error in try block. That's the reason I think it will endlessly execute and after 100th time Fatal error will be thrown.

In your try block's `$ship->create()`, you need to pass `Order Increment ID` and not `Order Entity ID`.

Comment: Thanks let me try with order increment id

Comment: I tried with $orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId()); and ...$shipmentId = $ship->create($orders->getIncrementId(), $items, 'Shipment created through ShipMailInvoice', true, true);....still getting same issue

Comment: I think the suggestion to use increment id was an addition not directly related to your issue. You have to implement some sort of a check, if an order has shipments already, so that in the next iteration the code $order->save() is not reached.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below code,

```
   public function automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder($observer)
{
    //$order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    $incrementid = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();      
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($incrementid);
        try {
            // Is the order shipable?
            if($order->canShip())
            {
             $shipmentid = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')->create($order->getIncrementId(), array());
            }
            //END Handle Shipment
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment(' Exception occurred during automaticallyInvoiceShipCompleteOrder action. Exception message: '.$e->getMessage(), false);
        }
        return $this;
}
```

Shipment Created now...